# EF Core 5.0 Adding many-to-many makes one-to-many unable to determine

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-5.0

I want to make use of the new many-to-many feature in ef core 5.0. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

My existing classes are

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
}
```

and

```
public class Notification
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public User Creator { get; set; }
    public User Updater { get; set; }
    public Notification()
    {
    }
}
```

I want to add a many-to-many relation between them so the classes are

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public ICollection<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Notification
{
    //[...]
    public ICollection<User> Recipients { get; set; }
}
```

Now `dotnet ef migrations add NotificationRecipients` results in `Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Notification.Recipients' of type 'ICollection<User>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`

After some research I found the `[InverseProperty()]` annotation so I added it to Notification.cs

```
public class Notification
{
    //[...]
    [InverseProperty("Notifications")]
    public ICollection<User> Recipients { get; set; }
}
```

The many-to-many now seems to be resolved but `dotnet ef migrations add NotificationRecipients` results in `Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Notification.Creator' of type 'User'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`

Is there any Annotation I can add to `Notification.Creator` and `Notification.Updater` or any other way to define the one-to-many relations between `User` and `Notification`?

I am using MSSQL as database.

Comment: I Cannot understand you made a many to many relation between user and notification and in the same time you need to make one to many relation between user and notification also !!! it's not doable you can add CreatorId and UpdaterId and add [NotMapped] to Creator property and Updater

Comment: I am pretty sure its Possible. The relations have different purposes and Creator and Updater have been added in previous migrations. CreatorId and UpdaterId are already DBColumns.

Comment: i mean it's not doable in this way, try to add creatorId and make creator NotMapped or manual configuration using fluent api as Ivan's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple relationships between two entities usually cannot be determined automatically and need configuration. Many things (and especially relationships related) in EF Core can only be configured only with fluent API.

So rather than looking for non existing or non intuitive data annotations, simply configure the desired relationships (at minimum - navigations properties and cardinality) fluently:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>(builder =>
{
    builder.HasOne(e => e.Creator).WithMany();
    builder.HasOne(e => e.Updater).WithMany();
    builder.HasMany(e => e.Recipients).WithMany(e => e.Notifications);
});
```

Comment: Probably you ment `builder.Entity<Notification>().*`?
If I try this then I am getting `The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<int>' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.` when I try to create my migration.

Comment: If you inherit `IdentityDbCiontext` as it seems, make sure to call `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` at the beginning of your `OnModelCreating` override. If that doesn't help, then you have another separate issue - EF Core reports the first one found, and when it is fixed - the next etc. This code should have fixed the relationship issue from your question. For other issues - new question.